# Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '26sb0' - Javascript service file not working

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

In my Vanilla JS project, I want to use a service file to fetch data from an API. When trying to log the data from the API call, I get the error **Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '26sb0'**

The files `index.html`, `index.js` and `apiService.js` are in the **src **folder.

I imported the javascript files in the index.html document:

```html
<script type="module" src="index.js" defer></script>
<script type="module" src="apiService.js" defer></script>
```

I make the API call in the apiService.js file:

```js
const apiUrl = 'https://api.spoonacular.com';

export const fetchData = async(path) => {
    const res = await fetch(`${apiUrl}/${path}`);
    const data = await res.json();
    return data;
};
```

Finally, I import the fetchData function in my index.js file and make an API call:

```js
import { fetchData } from './apiService';
const randomRecipePath = "recipes/random?apiKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
const testData = await fetchData(randomRecipePath);
console.log(testData);
```

Comment: There's no reference to `26sb0` anywhere in your code. You need to do some debugging to figure out where it is coming from.

Comment: What is the point of `<script type="module" src="apiService.js" defer></script>`? It doesn't do anything by itself. It is only useful when you `import` it form another module.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to reproduce the exact error you showed `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '26sb0'`. That error is probably coming from somewhere else in your code or the environment you are running the code from.

However, you said you were loading this code from HTML, so I assumed that your intention was to run this in the browser. So, after running your code on my local environment in Chrome, I found a flaw in your code that might explain why this wouldn't work in a browser. To put it very simply, because of how module resolution works in the browser, it cannot find the file.

When you are calling `import { fetchData } from './apiService'` the browser looks for a file called `apiService` but it does not exist. What you need to do is to append `.js` to the end of the reference in the import.

To look at this from a different angle, to be able to import a local file without specifying the extension you would need to configure the environment that your code is running in to resolve modules without extensions. This is possible to do in an environment like Node. Browsers, however, do not have this kind of configuration built in so you need to be exact and specify the extension.

Here's a working example using your code with the [JSONPlaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/) api:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<script type="module" src="index.js" defer></script>
<script type="module" src="apiService.js" defer></script>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
import { fetchData } from './apiService.js'; // add .js here

const randomRecipePath = "todos/1";
const testData = await fetchData(randomRecipePath);
console.log(testData);
```

**apiService.js**

```
const apiUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

export const fetchData = async(path) => {
  const res = await fetch(`${apiUrl}/${path}`);
  const data = await res.json();
  return data;
};
```

That should get you working in the browser. For the `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '26sb0'` error, you'll need to further debug like @Quentin recommended in the comments on your question.